# Grails how to JSONify domain object including its nested domain classes?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I am trying to do one to many domain mapping in grails.Here are the two classes :

```
class TNDetails {

String tn
String tnpk

static hasMany = [iccid: ICCID]

static mapping = {
    table 'ni_tn'
    version false
    tnpk column : 'TN_PK'
    tn column: 'TN'
    id column: 'TN_PK',name: 'tnpk'
    }

}

class ICCID {

String sim
String customer
static belongsTo = [tn: TNDetails]


static mapping = {
    table 'ni_sim'
    version false
    sim column: 'ICCID'
    customer column: 'CUSTOMER'
    tn column: 'TN_FK'
    id column: 'SIM_PK'
  }
}
```

The corresponding query can be written as : `select TN,ICCID from ni_tn,ni_sim where ni_tn.TN_PK = ni_sim.RELATED_TN and tn_pk=1290`.Now in my controller when i am fetch the details by passing tn_pk like this :

```
def index() {
    def pk = params.tnPK
    def details = TNDetails.findAll   {

        (tnpk == pk)

    }

    respond details
}
```

i get following result :
`[
    {
        "class": "com.evolving.resource.tn.TNDetails",
        "id": 1290,
        "tnpk": "1290",
        "iccid": [
            {
                "class": "com.evolving.resource.iccid.ICCID",
                "id": 4209
            }
        ],
        "tn": "447400002035"
    }
]`

**Now the problem here is it is not displaying the attributes `sim` and `customer`(from class ICCID)**.How do i display these two parameters also.What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by display attributes? In your view? Can you provide an more detailed example?

Comment: @saw303  : There is no view as such.I am returning a JSON object and the attributes like "sim" and "cutomer" are missing in the JSON.

Comment: What happens if you use `log.debug details as JSON`in your controller? What is the output? What Grails version do you use?

Comment: @saw303 : It gives same JSON object as i mentioned above.I am using grails 2.4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your:

```
respond details
```

to:

```
JSON.use("deep") {
    respond details as JSON
}
```

---

The Deep Converters fully render the associations (nested domainclass instances) and also handle circular relations ([documentation](https://grails.org/wiki/converters%20reference))

Comment: cool, the `deep` configuration tells grails to recursivly expand even nested objects.